# Регулярное выражение для удаления всех похожих строк

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, opencart

Есть модуль для парсинга SimplePars, работает на Опенкарт и для поиска и замены использует в том числе регулярные выражения.
В инструкции к нему (https://simplepars.top/index.php?page=note&n=37) я нашёл правило
`{reg[#^(.*?)\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)#m]}| - Удалит две Идентичные строки друг за другом`. Как составить правило, которое удалит все идентичные строки, а не только последовательные?

Comment: Возможно `#^(.*?)\R+(?=(?s:.*?)^\1$)#m`

Comment: Спасибо. Да, это подходит. Но я не могу ваш комментарий отметить верным

Comment: Так я его могу оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```php
#^(.*?)\R+(?=(?s:.*?)^\1$)#m
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(.*?)` - Первая захватывающая подмаска: ноль и более любых символов кроме перевода на новую строку, как можно меньше
- `\R+` - одна и более последовательностей перехода на новую строку
- `(?=` - начало блока предварительного просмотра вперёд:

  - `(?s:.*?)` - ноль и более любых символов, как можно меньше
  - `^` - начало строки
  - `\1` - то же значение, что и в первой подмаске
  - `$` - конец строки
- `)` - конец блока предварительного просмотра вперёд

Comment: Благодарю. Поторопился с самовольством. Отметил ваш ответ решением

Answer (score 0):

Так можно получить уникальные слова из текста. В примере ниже слово test возвращается только одно, повторные значения отсекаются.

```
'test regular expression check test'.match(/(\w+\b)(?!.*\1\b)/gmi) // ['regular', 'expression', 'check', 'test']
```

Comment: Мне нужны уникальные строки, а не слова. В строке может быть больше 1 слова

Answer (score -1):

В комментариях подсказали ответ `#^(.*?)\R+(?=(?s:.*?)^\1$)#m`. Он подходит